# How to add the textfield values to the array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I am having two field like product and quantity. After entering  the values in the field it must be stored in respective multi-dimension array. This can be happen multiple times as whenever entered new value it has to add with the existing one and represent in table view.

Comment: What have you done till now. Update us with the details?

Comment: What's the platform that you are developing for (iOS / Android) ? need details as @ShaikMahaboobBasha said

Answer (score 0):

Type in Apple, or Orange, and then a number.  Click add and it updates the table view.  If you don't type a number in the quantity I'm not sure what happens cause I didn't test it.

To add a new product, like Banana, type in a product that doesn't exist.  It will add it to the array and then total up any additional products added after that.

This example is always case specific with the product's name.

Since this is Titanium code and only uses basic objects, it should work in both Android and IOS, but I only tested IOS.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: 'vertical',
    backgroundColor: "white"
});

var products = [{
        productName: "Apple",
        quantity: 5 
    },
    {
        productName: "Orange",
        quantity: 10
    }];

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    layout: "horizontal",
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var productView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: "50%",
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout: "vertical"
});
view.add(productView);

var productName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Product Name:"
});
productView.add(productName);

var product = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    width: "90%",
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
productView.add(product);

var quantityView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: "50%",
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    layout: "vertical"
});
view.add(quantityView);

var productQuantity = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Quantity: "
});
quantityView.add(productQuantity);

var quantity = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    width: "90%",
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});

quantityView.add(quantity);
win.add(view);

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "Add",
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE
});
win.add(button);

function createRow(params){
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height: "50dp",
        layout: "horizontal"
    });
    var product = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: params.productName
    });
    row.add(product);
    var quantity = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        left: "20dp",
        text: params.quantity
    });
    row.add(quantity);
    return row;
}

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var index = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        if(products[i].productName === product.value){
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if(index > -1){
        products[index].quantity = parseFloat(products[index].quantity) + parseFloat(quantity.value);
        rows[index] = createRow(products[index]);

    } else {
        var newProduct = {
            productName: product.value,
            quantity: quantity.value
        };
        products.push(newProduct);
        rows.push(createRow(newProduct));
    }
    table.setData(rows);
});

var rows = [];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    top: "10dp"
});
win.add(table);

for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
    rows.push(createRow(products[i]));
}

table.setData(rows);
win.open();
```